# What's the measing of "lousy pun" in this context?

Tags: puns

I'm reading a Python (Computer programming language) doc: [PEP 3155 – Qualified name for classes and functions](https://peps.python.org/pep-3155/).

In the Rationale section, it says

> Python’s introspection facilities have long had poor support for nested classes. Given a class object, it is impossible to know whether it was defined inside another class or at module top-level; and, if the former, it is also impossible to know in which class it was defined. While use of nested classes is often considered poor style, the only reason for them to have second class introspection support is a lousy pun.

I don't understand the meaning of the last sentence "While use of nested classes... a lousy pun.". So "lousy pun" is not a good pun, right? The only reason to have good introspection support for nested classes is a lousy pun. What does *that* mean?

Thanks

Comment: “Second class” is the pun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Definitions**

Let's start with a few definitions.

1. Python classes - A class is a user-defined blueprint or prototype from which objects are created. Classes provide a means of bundling data and functionality together. See [Geeks for Geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-classes-and-objects/)
2. Second class - A set of people or things grouped together as the second best, i.e. "bad".
3. Pun - A joke exploiting the different possible meanings of a word or the fact that there are words which sound alike but have different meanings.

**The Pun**

The pun in this case hinges on the two meanings of the word class, which are listed above. With that in mind, let's answer your questions.

*So "lousy pun" is not a good pun, right?*

That's correct.

*The only reason to have **good** introspection support for nested classes is a lousy pun.*

No. The only reason for them to have **bad** introspection support is a lousy pun. Why? Because the author doesn't think there is any reason for Python to have bad introspection support, other than to be able to say that:

The only reason to have **second class** introspection support for nested classes is a lousy pun.

Comment: If people don’t see the pun, I don’t see how your explanation helps.